# Do the time taken to travel a fixed distance changes in two different inertial frame of reference in relative motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, relative-motion

I have calculated time taken to travel  a fixed distance by the object from two different frames of refrence. One frame was moving with uniform velocity wrt other . But time taken to cover the  equal distance was different in both frames

Comment: A rotating frame is not inertial, and you need to be careful about how you define a “fixed distance”.

Answer (score 0):

No the time remains same in both frames but distance wrt both frames changes

Answer (score 0):

Time is independent of frames. So it does not depend on your frame of reference whereas distance, velocity, acceleration, force etc. might change.